# javascript string.replace fails at German Umlaute

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am using a small Javascript/Jquery function to inject a  element into some text, if there is not already such an element.

The code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(function () {
    $(".replaceText").html(function (i, text) {
        if ($('.replaceText > span.dbOrange').length) {
            return;
        }
        else {
            return text.replace(/\w+\s\w+/, function (match) {
                return '<span class="dbOrange">' + match + '</span>';
            });
        }
    });
});
```

});

This works fine in 9 out of 10 cases. The first two words are styled with orange color and bold. However, if a the the second word contains an Umlaut like ä ö ü the Regex breaks at this character and it looks like the word would end there.

Can you help me with a more failsafe solution?

Kind regards

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280712/javascript-unicode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
/\S+\s\S+/
```

\S matches non-whitespace characters.

Comment: feel yourself hugged. Works like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

[`\w` is a shorthand for `[A-Za-z0-9_]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-word), which does not contain the umlaut character. If you want other ranges included, you'll need to create an explicit set of acceptable characters.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is a common issue for non english characters in Javascript regular expressions. They will not be recognized by `\w`. You will have to specify the unicode representation `\uXXXXX` for each of the special characters separately