# Select first 2 words with jQuery and wrap them with <span> tag

Tags: jquery

How can I select with jQuery the first two words in a sentence, wrap them with a span tag and add a br tag after it?

Something like this:

```
<p><span>Lorem ipsum</span><br/> quosque tandem</p>
```

But add the span and br tag dynamically.

I can only do that for the first word with this code:

```
$('p').each(function(){
    var featureTitle = $(this);
    featureTitle.html( featureTitle.text().replace(/(^\w+)/,'<span>$1</span><br/>') );
  });
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('p').html(function (i, html) {
    return html.replace(/(\w+\s\w+)/, '<span>$1</span><br/>')
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/crBJg/

Answer (score 1):

And for those who are working with umlauts (äöåü etc.), you might want to use `\S+\s\S+` instead of `\w+\s\w+` to make this work properly.

See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/12845431/5349534