# Select first two words of h2 tag and wrap in span tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wanted to find all h2 tags on a page and then wrap first two words in a span tag. I have checked [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182113/select-first-2-words-with-jquery-and-wrap-them-with-span-tag/15182155#15182155), but it didn't help me.

I am able to do as per this link and dd span to first 2 words, but the only issue is that if I have html inside h2 tag for eg I have hyperlink inside h2 tag.

Can anyone please help me how to make this code so as html is ignored and only first two words are considered?

Any help is really appreciated!

---

#### My Fiddle :

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rigid/jornvLee/2/)

---

#### My JS :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
    jQuery('h2').html(function (i, html) {
        return html.replace(/(\w+\s\w+)/, '<span>$1</span>')
    });
});
```

---

#### My HTML :

```
<h2>
    <a title="test post 2" href="#">
        test text dolor sit enum
    </a>
</h2>
<h2>lorem ipsum dolor sit enum</h2>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
  jQuery('h2').html(function (i, html) {
    if(/<[a-z][\s\S]*>/i.test(html)) {
      html = jQuery.parseHTML(html);
      return html[0].innerHTML.replace(/(\w+\s\w+)/, '<span>$1</span>');
    }
    return html.replace(/(\w+\s\w+)/, '<span>$1</span>');
  });

});
```

```css
h2 {
  color:#f2f2f2;
}
h2 span {
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2><a title="test post 2" href="#">test text dolor sit enum</a></h2>
<h2>lorem ipsum dolor sit enum</h2>
```

Comment: @JoshCrozier
Your answer didn't work for me rather the answer I have accepted works great.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `text()` function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
  jQuery('h2').text(function (i, txt) {
    console.log ( txt.replace(/(\w+\s\w+)/, '<span>$1</span>'))
  });

});
```

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/spdthfgx/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    var h2 = $('h2 > a').html();
    alert(h2.replace(/(\w+\s\w+)/, '<span>$1</span>'));
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y3llowjack3t/jornvLee/3/

Comment: this doesnot work. There is no span around 2 words and moreover only first h2 tag is showing no all h2

Answer (score 0):

```
var h2 = $('h2').html().split(' ');
$('span').html(h2[0] + ' ' + h2[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `JQuery` to get the text within the HTML, then use `text()` and `match` to find the first 2 words, and finally replace that text in the HTML wrapping it with `<span>`:

```
$(document).ready(function($){ 
  $('h2').html(function (i, html) {
    var text = $($.parseHTML(html)).text().match(/\w+\s\w+/)[0];
    return html.replace(text, '<span>'+text+'</span>');;
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j4fd86aw/6/